# Printing a long line in R without automatic newline

Tags: r

I have a long line which I would like to print to the screen, it is data in `dat` and I call it with

```
dat = read.csv("grades.csv", header=TRUE)
print(dat[2,])
```

What I get is

```
                 Name Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Quiz1 Quiz2 Quiz3 Quiz4
2  Lname** Fname*****  93.7    97  87.8  62.8  95.7   100   100   100    90
  Quiz5 Quiz6 Quiz7 Quiz8 Quiz9 Quiz10 HMWK
2    90    62   100    60    80     80  100
```

but I get this regardless of the terminal screeen size. If I stretch the terminal, I would like to have it all print to one line instead of automatic newline. How can I achieve this?

*** note *** : grade numbers have been changed to protect the innocent!

Comment: This should have been something you could have found by following the links in the ?print page.

Comment: You should understand that there are several different "console"-like implementations of the `R` terminal, not to mention just running `R` from a shell.  You haven't mentioned your setup.

Answer (score 3):

You can set this in `options`, e.g., try `options(width = 1000)`. The default is 80 characters ("normally", according to `?options`).